# Replace mustache tags in JS file and output the replaced JS

Tags: mustache, webpack-2, preprocessor

I have a file `config.js` with some Mustache templates inside, something like this:

```
export default {
  VAR1: {{var1}},
  VAR2: '{{var2}}'
};
```

I want to process that file before anything else so it would go through the Webpack pipeline (Babel, etc) as this (supposing that `var1` is set to `42` and `var2` is set to `hello`):

```
export default {
  VAR1: 42,
  VAR2: 'hello'
};
```

I’ve tried to use `mustache-loader` but it seems to create a function representing the compiled template file, instead of the result file, no matter the setting I use.

Is there any way (loader, whatever) that would make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious, I’ve solved the problem with `render-template-loader` instead, chained with `extract-loader`.